# Cmake complains about wrong number of arguments

Tags: cmake

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(
  wtdbo
PROPERTIES
  VERSION ${VERSION_SERIES}.${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}
  SOVERSION ${WTDBO_SOVERSION}
  DEBUG_POSTFIX "d"
)
```

The error is:

> CMake Error at src/Wt/Dbo/CMakeLists.txt:18 (SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES):
>     set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments

If I remove it it configures just fine.
Any idea why?

Thanks,
Omer

Comment: I don't know cmake, but I thought this can't be too difficult, so I googled a bit, and it looks fine according to the basic manual information I could find. Suggestions: look at instructions before this one, post a bit more of your script and include line numbers, look at where macros are defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you have the variables set correctly? I've checked with this CMakeLists.txt file, and it works correctly:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(test CXX)
ADD_LIBRARY(wtdbo SHARED test.cc)
SET(WTDBO_SOVERSION 1)
SET(VERSION_SERIES 1)
SET(VERSION_MAJOR 0)
SET(VERSION_MINOR 0)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(
  wtdbo
PROPERTIES
  VERSION ${VERSION_SERIES}.${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}
  SOVERSION ${WTDBO_SOVERSION}
  DEBUG_POSTFIX "d"
)
```

However, if I comment out the `SET(WTDBO_SOVERSION 1)` line I get the same error message as you do. The help for `set_target_properties` is as follows, so you are definitely doing the right thing:

> Targets can have properties that
>   affect how they are built.
>
> ```
> set_target_properties(target1 target2 ...
>            PROPERTIES prop1 value1
>            prop2 value2 ...)
> ```
>
> Set properties on a target.  The
>   syntax for the command is to list all
>   the files you want to change, and then
>   provide the values you want to set
>   next.  You can use any prop value pair
>   you want and extract it later with the
>   `GET_TARGET_PROPERTY` command.

Answer (score 11):

Remember that this is a macro, so symbols are replaced before being evaluated. This means that symbols that are empty strings will be replaced to nothing before being evaluated. Thus, if WTDBO_SOVERSION is "" then

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(wtdbo PROPERTIES SOVERSION ${WTDBO_SOVERSION})
```

would become

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(wtdbo PROPERTIES SOVERSION)
```

and this would trigger the error. If empty strings are valid for your purpose then surround the symbol in quotes. e.g.

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(wtdbo PROPERTIES SOVERSION "${WTDBO_SOVERSION}")
```